# How would you answer this django interview question?

Tags: python, django

I recently did a programming question for a pre-interview for a certain company. The questions was:

Create a django app, test driven of course, to display Fibonacci's sequence to the world. The app should take an index number and display the resulting Fibonacci sequence. Additionally, there should be a page that shows the most recent generated sequences.  Also, Fibonacci is a bit impatient and doesn’t want to wait around forever, so make sure you take steps to make sure your webserver runs efficiently.

I came up with the following:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.http import Http404

LARGEST_SEQUENCE = [0,1] 
LARGEST = 1 
LATEST = []

def fib(n): 
    """Calculate the nth fibonacci sequence""" 
    global LARGEST
    if n > LARGEST: 
        while n > LARGEST: 
            next = LARGEST_SEQUENCE[LARGEST] + LARGEST_SEQUENCE[LARGEST-1] 
            #print 'appending ', next
            LARGEST_SEQUENCE.append(next)   
            LARGEST += 1  
        return LARGEST_SEQUENCE 
    else: 
        return LARGEST_SEQUENCE[0:n+1] 

def latest(request):
    results=[]
    for n in LATEST:
        result = fib(n)
        results.append((n,result))
    return direct_to_template(request, 'latest.html', {'results':results})

def index(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            n=int(request.POST.get('n'))
        except:
            return Http404
        result = fib(n)
        if len(LATEST) >=  5:
            LATEST.pop()
        LATEST.insert(0,n)
    else:
        result = None
    return direct_to_template(request, 'base.html', {'result':result})
```

The "latest" view is my 2nd version because the 1st version didn't work consistently. The original version stored the result from "index" in LATEST. LATEST was originally a list of fib sequences (lists) instead of a list of recent values of N.

I guess my main question is, is it bad to store the largest fib sequence generated during runtime in the views.py file? I know this isn't persistent, but the instructions never really gave details on how things should be done. What do you guys think, and how would you have approached the problem?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

Every linear reccurence equation can be solve directly.
In fibonacci's case the equation is

```
f_n+2 = f_n+1 + f_n
f_1 = 1
f_2 = 1
```

The solution to this is:

```
f_n = 1/sqrt(5) * ((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n - 1/sqrt(5) * ((1-sqrt(5))/2)^n
```

Use this direct formula.
For how to get to it look for linear reccurence equation solving. E.g. [here](http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wdj/book/node29.html).

Because of floating point errors, you should round the result to the nearest integer.

Comment: In Python, this means use `**` instead of `^` and `int(round())` not just `int()`.

Comment: Separately, I'm not sure this would impress them -- is this question about storing info with Django or is it about knowing "Every linear reccurence equation can be solved directly"?

Comment: when I interview people I am impressed by the correct way of doing things - if what I am asking  can be done better in a different way that I intent than I suck, not the candidate :D

Comment: It's a good answer, you've got my vote, I just wonder if the OP knows what the question was looking for.

Comment: Ok I see how this is useful in calculating the nth fib number quickly but the question asked for the sequence. does this solution imply that, say, if the 50th fibonacci number was requested, I would calculate each fib # from 1-50 and output that and not store any of the results? Does it make sense to store the largest fibonacci sequence generated and reuse already generated results (which was what I did)?

Comment: @user701632 No, you shouldn't use this if you need the whole sequence anyway, it's far more computationally intensive.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the well-know formula for computation in `O(1)` it fails for large numbers (ie 100).

I would do the next for the fibonacci thing:

```
def fib(n):
    "Complexity: O(log(n))"
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    i = n - 1
    (a, b) = (1, 0)
    (c, d) = (0, 1)
    while i > 0:
        if i % 2:
            (a, b) = (d * b + c * a,  d * (b + a) + c * b)
        (c, d) = (c * c + d * d, d * (2 * c + d))
        i = i / 2
    return a + b
```

And for the lastes numbers, I would create a model.

```
from django.db import models

class Fibonacci(models.Model):
    parameter = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

And for the view I would just do this:

```
from models import Fibonacci

def index(request):
    result = None
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            n=int(request.POST.get('n'))
        except:
            return Http404
        try:
            result = Fibonacci.objects.get(pk=n)
            result.time = datetime.now()
        except DoesNotExist:
            result = str(fib(n))
            result = Fibonacci(n, result, datetime.now())
        result.save()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'base.html', {'result':result.result})
```

Using models to retrive the last n entries is pretty simple.

Comment: The way I interpreted the question was that it wanted a sequence as the end result, not just the nth fibonacci number. Was I mistaken?

Comment: @user701632 In that case it would be easier just precompute the possible answers and store it in the model. Retrieve the answers and thats it.

Comment: @user701632 Actually it is what OP was asking. Shame on me.